# Wunused-but-set-variable warning with C++11 auto

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, compiler-warnings, auto

I am getting a -Wunused-but-set-variable warning with GCC v4.6 with the code below:

```
for ( auto i : f.vertexIndices ) {
    Sy_MatrixFuzzyHashable< Vector3f > wrapper( cp );
    if ( !vMapper.contains( wrapper ) ) {
        mesh.vertexNormals() << cp;
        i.normal = mesh.vertexNormals().size() - 1;
     } else {
        i.normal = vMapper.value( wrapper );
     }
}
```

The warning specifically is:

```
warning: variable 'i' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

The warning would make sense if `i` was a copy of an element, but since `vertexIndices` is a `QList` object (an STL-compliant Qt container class) the range-based for loop should call the begin() and end() iterator getters, which will always return a non-const iterator (as long as the container is non-const - which it is).

I can't currently test if it is working as I think it should because I'm changing my code base to take advantage of the new C++11 features, so nothing compiles yet.  But I was hoping someone could tell me if this warning is is nonsense, or if I have misunderstood auto and range-based for loops...

Comment: "The warning would make sense if `i` was a copy of an element": you answered your own question: `i` **is** a copy of an element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is that your for loop, as written like this:

```
for ( auto i : f.vertexIndices )
```

is getting back a *copy* of the stored vertex, not a reference to it.  The compiler warning here says that you're then setting the value of `i` but not reading it because you're modifying the temporary copy rather than the stored vertex.

If you change it to

```
for ( auto& i : f.vertexIndices )
```

then this problem should go away, since you're actually modifying the vertices stored internally.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've been a fool.  I keep thinking that auto in this scenario would represent an iterator, but of course it's dereferencing it and giving me a copy of the element.  Thank you!  I have a lot of re-typing to do...

Comment: @cbamber85 : That would imply that you think some iterator has a data member named `normal`, given that the code you showed has `i.normal = ...;` multiple times...

Comment: I said I was a fool didn't I?

Comment: @cbamber85 : Fair enough. :-P

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood `auto`. This loop:
`for ( auto i : f.vertexIndices )`
should really be :
`for ( auto & i : f.vertexIndices )`

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#C.2B.2B

illustrates an example but yes, it needs to be a reference object for the foreach

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
      int myint[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

      for (int& i: myint)
      {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
      }
    }
```

or

```
    #include <QList>
    #include <QDebug>

    int main() {
            QList<int> list;
            list << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5;
            foreach (int i, list) {
                    qDebug() << i;
            }
    }
```

- Courtesy of Wikipedia